# Flowtype – how to export and import types?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I've followed https://flow.org/en/docs/install/, and flow is working fine when used in single files, like this:

```
 // @flow 

type NumberAlias = number;

const n: NumberAlias = "123";
```

Flow will correctly point out that:

```
  5: const n: NumberAlias = "123";
                            ^^^^^ string. This type is incompatible with
  5: const n: NumberAlias = "123";
              ^^^^^^^^^^^ number
```

**The problem arises when** I try to export a type from moduleA and import that type in moduleB:

(moduleA.js)

```
// @flow 

export type NumberAlias = number;
```

(moduleB.js)

```
// @flow

import type { NumberAlias } from './moduleA';

const n: NumberAlias = 123;
```

Flow complains:

```
src/moduleB.js:3
  3: import type { NumberAlias } from './moduleA';
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ ./moduleA. Required module not found
```

Isn't this exactly how it's described in https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/?

Folder structure is:

```
src/
    moduleA.js
    moduleB.js
.flowconfig
package.json
```

Comment: .flowconfig is empty

Comment: do you happen to find out the answer to your question?

Comment: No, I gave up and switched to Typescript :[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked as you'd expect when I set it up, using the two files provided sitting in a `src` folder under my project's root.  `moduleB.js`:

[image: Flow error]

If I fail to put `// @flow` in `Module A`, the compiler treats `NumberAlias` as `any`, and fails to complain.  I initially forgot to add it, and this threw me for a few minutes.

The only way I could find to produce the "moduleA not found" error was to change the file extension (or file name) for moduleA.  For example, if the file is called `moduleA.ts`, `ModuleA.js`, or simply `moduleA`, the import will fail to resolve as above.

---

Incidentally, both

```
import type { NumberAlias } from './moduleA';
```

and

```
import type { NumberAlias } from './moduleA.js';
```

resolve just fine in my local environment.  You might try the second format?

---

Provided these conditions are met:

- Both files live in the same folder
- Both have a `.js` (or `.jsx`) extension
- The filenames match the import statements exactly
- Both contain the `// @flow` comment

The code you provided works using Flow 0.57.3 with Node 8.7.0.  In light of the error message, I'd suggest triple checking the filenames and extensions especially.

Comment: what if files are in different folders?

Comment: Just set this up in a fresh environment, and as you say it worked just fine now! Hard to say what went wrong originally. Docs have definitely been updated since then

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, one can put all types into file `anyname.js` and put it into `flow-typed` directory. Then all the types would be exported automaticaly, without `import`.